# What type of sugar is produced A. Tutton's Paper on the Synthesis of Glucose?

Tags: organic-chemistry, biochemistry, synthesis, food-chemistry

https://www.nature.com/articles/037007b0

At the end of all the chemical reactions, a sugary substance is identified by what sugar it is is not specified so I would like to know what it may be. (On a side note, if there is a other method of artificial synthesizing glucose please mention it)